# Point-wise limit of finite valued functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Let $X$ be a second countable topological vector space. Does there exist any sequence of finite valued functions $f_n\colon X\to X$ converging point-wise to the identity mapping on $X$?

Comment: Does "finite valued" just mean "takes values in $X$"?

Comment: @LSpice: I think it means that the image of $f_n$ is a finite set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer a question raised in comments: if $X$ is merely separable then this can fail.  Let $X = \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ with the product topology, which is a Hausdorff topological vector space.  Then $X$ is separable.  ([Any product of continuum many separable spaces is separable.](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2009/11/06/product-of-separable-spaces/)  Alternatively, viewing $X$ as the space of all functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, one can show that the set of polynomials with rational coefficients is dense.)

Now let $f_n : X \to X$ be a sequence of finite-range functions converging pointwise to some $f$.  Let $A = \bigcup_n f_n(X)$ be the union of the images of the $f_n$, so that $A$ is countable.  Then the number of sequences of elements of $A$ has cardinality at most $(\aleph_0)^{\aleph_0} = \mathfrak{c}$, so that the set $B$ of possible limits of sequences from $A$ likewise has cardinality at most $\mathfrak{c}$.  But the image of $f$ is contained in $B$.  Since $X$ has cardinality $\mathfrak{c}^\mathfrak{c} > \mathfrak{c}$, the function $f$ cannot be surjective.

Comment: It was really great.

Comment: Let $X$ be a separable topological space and $A$ be a countable dense subset in $X$. Any point $x$ of $X$ is the limit of a sequence of elements contained in $A$. Does not it show that size of $X$ is at most $\mathfrak{c}$?

Comment: @AliBagheri: Nope, your second sentence is false in general.  We can say that every neighborhood of $x$ contains a point of $A$.  This does not imply that there is a sequence of points of $A$ which converge to $x$, if $X$ is not first countable (or more generally, if $X$ is not sequential).  Indeed in this example, if you take the polynomials with rational coefficients, the limit of any sequence of them is Baire class one and in particular Borel.  Yet their closure is all of $X$ which contains lots of non-Borel functions.

Answer (score 8):

I think it is true (even in the more general setting of second countable  topological spaces). Let $\{A_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a countable basis of the topology of $X$. For ${n\in\mathbb{N}}$ let $\Pi_n$ be the finite partition of $X$   generated   by the sets $A_1,\dots, A_n$, and let $f_n:X\to X$  be constant on each $E\in\Pi_n$, with $f_n(E)\in E$. 
Then $f_n(x)\to x$ for any $x\in X$. (Indeed, for any $x\in X$ and for any nbd $U$ of $x$ there is $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x\in A_{n_0}\subset U$. Then by construction, for any $n\ge n_0$ there holds $f_n(x)\in U$).

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean "even in the more ..."?

Comment: I mean, not only topological *vector* spaces, but  just topological spaces.

Comment: It seems that this is a characterization of second countability: a Hausdorff (?) topological space is second countable if and only if there is a sequence of finitely valued functions which converge to the identity pointwise.

Comment: It seems that finite valued functions $f_n$ are all even measurable!

Comment: @ Pietro Majer  What about if we just assume $X$ is separable?

Comment: @erz: I don't think so.  For instance, if $X$ has this property, then so does any weaker topology on $X$.  But it can be possible to take a second countable topology and weaken it to one which is not second countable (but still Hausdorff).  For instance, the norm and weak topologies on a separable Banach space.

Comment: @GABB For a separable topological space $X$ I think it is not true; maybe separable AND first countable suffices. If $X$ is not first countable, it could happen that the only convergent sequences are those eventually constant; this would imply that the point-wise limits of the $f_n$ are values of the $f_n$ themselves, so if the $f_n$ converge to the identity, $X$ would be countable.

Comment: @Pietro Majer  Even for separable topological *vector* space?

Comment: I do not have an example handy for TVS. An uncountable separable topological space, all of whose convergent sequences are stationary, is $X:=\beta\mathbb{N}$. Thus no sequence of finite range functions $f_n:X\to X$ can converge point-wise to the identity.

Comment: @PietroMajer: I posted another answer with a separable TVS which fails this property.

Comment: @NateEldredge you are right, and so thanks to your counterexamples the correct conclusion is that this property is strictly in between of second countability and separability (even for Hausdorff TVS's). I think, that is rather remarkable.

Comment: As observed in Nate Eldredge's example, this property for $X$ also implies that $X$ is *sequentially separable* (there exists a countable subset $D$ of $X$ such that any point of $X$ is limit of a sequence in $D$).

Comment: In fact a google search on *sequential separability* gives quite  a detailed picture

Answer (score 5):

I'll assume that $X$ is Hausdorff.

A Hausdorff topological vector space is metrizable iff it is first countable. Hence, $X$ is metrizable and has a dense subset $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$. Define $f_n(x)$ as an arbitrary closest of $x_1,...,x_n$ to $x$. Then $f_n(x)\to x$. Indeed, $d(x,f_n(x))$ does not increase, and for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is $n$ such that $d(x,f_n(x))\le d(x,x_n)<\varepsilon$.

Comment: I find amusing that we had two different proofs with very similar wording :)

Comment: @PietroMajer I think, they are similar: in my proof I just use a particular base of topology (balls). Mine is probably a bit easier to come up with, and yours is more general.

Comment: In fact your proof also works without assuming Hausdorff -- then the topology is induced by a semi-distance, but the conclusion holds true.

Comment: @PietroMajer you are right, although it still uses the algebraic structure unlike your proof.